# Xamarin.Forms Popup Page from background service

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working with Xamarin.Forms on a project which is required to have a background service that will lookup for a date to remind the user of some important activity, but has to behave like an alarm and to be like a popup page or some sort of where I can make some XAML and bind some pieces of information from SQLite.

I have made a service that works in the background, I have made a subscription via MessagingCenter, and all is working so well the only thing I can't do is just from the background to simply open designed page bindings and VM will do the rest of the job.

I spent 5 days searching around but nothing seems to work...
Help will be well appreciated.

Comment: please post the relevant code so we can understand what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a different solution to my problem. using AlarmManager here is a very simple code that will just start the new activity I have just created a new constructor in app.xaml.cs that will open the reminder page as the main page. and LoadApp will be called from ReminderActivity but with
LoadApplication(new App(true));

```
void LoadAlarm()
    {
        var alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
    
        var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 600 * 1000, pending);

    }
```

and

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ReminderActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

    }
}
```